# Bootstrap 4 "data-toggle" breaks the two way binding in angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular7

I have two radio buttons and I am using Bootstrap 4 radio buttons template.

Here, I'd like to keep the Bootstrap way of displaying the radio buttons. if I remove `data-toggle="buttons"`two-way binding works properly, otherwise `SelectionRadio` value does not update.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" >
   <label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info active">
       <input type="radio" name="options" [(ngModel)]="SelectionRadio" 
       value="Value1" autocomplete="off" checked /> Selection1
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info">
       <input type="radio" name="options" [(ngModel)]="SelectionRadio" 
       value="Value2" autocomplete="off"/> Selection2
  </label>
</div>

<div>{{ SelectionRadio }}</div>
```

Comment: If you plan to use Bootstrap with Angular, I strongly recommend [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home), instead of the standard jQuery implementation.

Comment: I will try that thanks.

Comment: That worked nicely, I will probably use ng-bootstrap now.

Comment: You will not regret it. :-)